# wildfly 16, log4j 2.17.0, NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY

Tags: log4j, wildfly

I get an error during wildfly startup with the following message:

NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY

The message also say that this error occurs in undertow deployment. Could anybody give me a hint of what is going on here and how to solve that?

Below is the beginning of the stack trace.

```
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@24.0.1.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:90)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
```

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource.(ConfigurationSource.java:56)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.(NullConfiguration.java:32)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.(LoggerContext.java:85)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
at deployment.taggable-server.war//org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.api@2.14.1//org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.api@2.14.1//org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)

Comment: _org.apache.logging.log4j.api@2.14.1_: you are using `log4j-core` version 2.17.0, but you didn't upgrade `log4j-api` to the same version (or you have an older version hanging around). `log4j-api` has no vulnerabilities, but its version should be synchronized with the version of `log4j-core`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I missed that mismatch. Exclusion of logging API from deployment as suggested by @James fixed my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring boot Log4j2 version 2.15.0 EMPTY\_BYTE\_ARRAY error in wildfly server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333905/spring-boot-log4j2-version-2-15-0-empty-byte-array-error-in-wildfly-server)

Comment: @madx answer looks like a solution to their problem. I'll give them a hint.

Comment: I'm still trying to fix this one out. So Constants is missing EMTPY_BYTE_ARRAY in older versions, yet I've excluded the logging subsystem and log4j 2.17.2 is the only version of log4j files I have. This is quite puzzling. I still say jar hell is worse than DLL hell :-)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had the same problem, you can solve it like this:

1. For a `war`:

   with a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` inside `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` like this:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
     <deployment>
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j.api"/>
       </exclusions>
     </deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```
2. For an `ear`:

   with a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` inside `src/main/application/META-INF/` like this:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <jboss-deployment-structure>
     <sub-deployment name="mywar.war">
        <exclusions>
           <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j.api"/>
       </exclusions>
     </sub-deployment>
   </jboss-deployment-structure>
   ```

Comment: I wrote the comment to @James answer with the same solution while you posted this. Thanks. Comments are poorly formatted here.

Comment: Sorry! I haven't seen the comment!  Thank you for  accepting mine. Anyway I think that many will have the same problem in the next few days, as soon as they upgrade log4j dependencies.

Comment: I've excluded the entire logging subsystem from JBoss and still getting this error. Honestly I think the better approach if you're not using the built in log4j to exclude the subsystem via <exclude-subsystems>

Answer (score 2):

You need to [exclude the API module](http://docs.wildfly.org/26/Admin_Guide.html#how-do-i-log4j2) from your deployment. Your other option is to use WildFly 26 which include the 2.16 version of the API.

Comment: Thanks for this tip that resolved my issue. In particular I did the following: create a file named ````jboss-deployment-structure.xml```` with the content below and put it into ````src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jboss-deployment-structure.xml````.

file content:

````
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
     <exclusions>
        <module name="org.apache.logging.log4j.api"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
````

Answer (score 1):

update the  log4j and log4j-api to 2.16.0 version.

if you are using the  spring-boot so, add  tag in pom.xml

```
 <properties> 
    <log4j2-version>2.16.0</log4j2-version>
  </properties>
```

and

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.16.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

in the pom.xml

Comment: If you're using spring-boot it should pull in log4j-api automatically. Won't hurt to add the dependency, just shouldn't be necessary unless some other dependency is pulling in a different one and then I'd opt to exclude the old version.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating log4j version to lower version and it worked.
Always check whether you have same version of artifacts **(log4j-api and log4j-core)**

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.17.1</version>
    </dependency>
```