# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY

Tags: java

I'm learning selenium and trying to run the below code but it throws the exception .NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY . Please help me understand what is going wrong with this simple program.

```
package newpackage;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException

import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.*;


public class spp {      

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String excelFilePath = "./src/DataFiles/GMD.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(excelFilePath);
    
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    int rows = sheet.getLastRowNum();
    System.out.println(rows);   
    
}
}
```

Console:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY

```
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource.<clinit>(ConfigurationSource.java:56)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.NullConfiguration.<init>(NullConfiguration.java:32)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext.<clinit>(LoggerContext.java:85)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.createContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:254)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.locateContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:218)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:136)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:123)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.selector.ClassLoaderContextSelector.getContext(ClassLoaderContextSelector.java:117)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:150)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.getContext(Log4jContextFactory.java:47)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getContext(LogManager.java:196)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.getLogger(LogManager.java:599)
at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.<clinit>(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:56)
at newpackage.spp2.main(spp2.java:17)
```

Comment: you are trying to access a field that doesn't exist. what line do you get that exception at? also: for future reference: javascript and java are not the same

Comment: This generally happens when you have incompatible versions of dependencies.

Comment: XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

Comment: No that is not where the exception is thrown.  Please show us the **complete** stacktrace.

Comment: Updated the question. Please check

Comment: Seems consistent with a log4j version mismatch. Are you using maven? You might want to check your pom.xml. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70333905/spring-boot-log4j2-version-2-15-0-empty-byte-array-error-in-wildfly-server

Answer (score 5):

OK so this is nothing to do with the excel file that you are loading or (probably) your application code at all.

What is happening is that when

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource
```

is being initialized ... deep in the log4j 2.x implementation code ... it is running into binary compatibility problem.  The code for `ConfigurationSource` that is being depends on a class called

```
org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Constants
```

and is trying to use a constant in that class called `EMPTY_BYTE_ARRAY`.  That field was present when the `ConfigurationSource` class was compiled.  But it is NOT present in the version of `Constants` that the classloader found ... which happens to match the most recent version of the log4j 2.x source code.

Now `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.ConfigurationSource` is in the `log4j-core` dependency while `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Constants` is in `log4j-api`.

So this strongly suggests that you have non-matching versions of the `log4j-core` and `log4j-api` classes on the (runtime) classpath for your application.

---

<sup>(I previously thought this was due to bad patching, but I missed the fact that there are two distinct `Constants` classes in the log4j code base.)</sup>

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70474648/wildfly-16-log4j-2-17-0-nosuchfielderror-empty-byte-array) suggests it is due to incompatible versions of log4j-api and log4j-core on the classpath.

Comment: You are correct.  There are two `Constants` classes `org.apache.logging.log4j.core.util.Constants` and `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.Constants`, and `ConfigurationSource` depends on the latter.

Comment: Thanks everyone for pitching in. Problem is due to incompatible versions of log4j-api and log4j-core .jar files. Added correct versions, now it is working.

Comment: What are the compatible versions? Im stuck with the same issue